# Get full path of selected file in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I need a JSF button which allows user to browse and select a particular file, then I need my program to retrieve full path of the file.

This functionality is required when user runs the client portion from the server itself (i.e. browses to the file in the same server which hosts the web app). If the user sends request from another machine, then uploading the file is enough.

For now, I am using h:inputFile tag.

```
 <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{TrainingDirectoryBean.file}"></h:inputFile>
```

My bean : TrainingDirectoryBean has the following property

```
protected Part file;
```

But I can't get full path from it. What is the solution?

Comment: I don't see a reason why browsing on the server would make any difference. What makes you think it does?

Comment: I know it does not, that's why I am looking for other solution. For now I am just using a text box where user can type in the full path of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSF `<h:inputFile>` component generates a HTML `<input type="file">` element which is officially only capable of sending the file content along with the sole file name — although certain browsers, particularly the one developed by some team in Redmond, also send the full file path along with the file name due to a security bug; which should thus certainly not be relied upon as it may be fixed and removed in future versions.

In HTML terms, there does not exist any element which allows the enduser to select a full file path from its local disk file system and send it in its entirety (without the associated file content) to the server. Since JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code producer, it isn't possible in JSF either.

Consider creating a [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) based [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) which you in turn embed the usual way in your HTML page (or JSF page, depending on the perspective how you interpret things). The Swing [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) is capable of the task of selecting a local disk file system location and obtaining the full path. You can in turn send this information via [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to the server (don't forget to sign the applet to avoid bothering and worrying the enduser about the security warnings it may produce).

Comment: Thank you BalusC. Isn't there a way to build a custom File Browser? Like a button which when clicked sends request to server to browse certain path (like home directory at first click), server responds with details of files and folders in that directory? I hope such a solution already exists.

Comment: This is answered in last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I need to use JSF backed by java beans though.

Comment: Uh, JSF is just a HTML code generator. You can easily embed applets in a JSF page as well. Using Javascript and JSF components which generate hidden command components, the applet can easily interact with a backing bean.