# Integration of Swing Applet with JSF 2.2 for FileChoosing

Tags: java, swing, jsf-2, applet, jfilechooser

I'm looking a way to use an applet with JSF 2.2.
For security purpose, my web application is under one virtual machine (one IP) and the directories I want to access are on another virtual machine (another IP).

I read about [Get full path of selected file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823700/get-full-path-of-selected-file-in-jsf) and [JWSFileChooserDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/JWSFileChooserDemoProject/src/components/JWSFileChooserDemo.java) .
I googled but still didn't find a clear example on how to integrate an Applet with JSF.
If someone can help me on this, to share some links, explanations, code examples... it would be really cool.

Comment: JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You just have to write JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output. How would you do it in "plain HTML"? Note that you can just use "plain HTML" in a JSF page as well.

Comment: Yeah my question is maybe not well asked. It's more about how you do create an simple Applet(Class,methods,etc) and how do you call it via "plain HTML" or JSF generated HTML whatever. So i understand that the integration will not be the hard stuff. I just don't know how an applet works :). I will try to read more about that so and post another question if i'm stuck with the applet creation. But i was hoping to have some example to get a frame to begin with and then add JSFFileCHooser.

Comment: Well, start with Oracle's own Swing and Applet tutorials.

Comment: Be sure to go through the links in the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) here at SO.  In my biased (I wrote it) opinion, it contains some of the best applet related links.